# what does "ccout" mean in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

I recently learned assembly,something like `ccout "* *"` the function is printing `"**"`. I searched many times , don't know why there is no definition of `ccout` online
,so what do you think

Comment: Which assembly? [tag:arm]? What's `printint`? Is [this definition](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/ch07s09s02.html) which pops up as the first hit when you Google for "ccout" the one that's not online? I think you haven't given your question nearly enough thought.

Comment: I use masm32,don't know what kind,but it's like "print"

Answer (score 0):

This is an extern C++ function that is used in the assembler code, see this thread [How to call C++ functions in my assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911578/how-to-call-c-functions-in-my-assembly-code)

This is why it is named *ccout* (the cout function inherited from C++)...