# How do I link a C++ subroutine to an x86 assembly program?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to make a simple assembly program that prints "Hello!" once, waits one second, then prints it again. Since sleep functions are relatively complex in assembly, and I'm not that good at it, I decided using C++ would be the way to go to make the Sleep subroutine. Here's the C++ program:

```
// Sleep.cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void Sleep(int TimeMs) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(TimeMs));
}
```

I then compiled this sleep function into an assembly program using "gcc -S Sleep.cpp" then compiled it into an object file using "gcc -c Sleep.s"

I am trying to call this C++ subroutine from assembly. I heard that you provide parameters to C++ subroutines by pushing them onto the stack, here's my assembly code so far:

```
        global    _main
        extern    _puts
        extern    Sleep
        section   .text
_main:    
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp,    rsp
        sub     rsp,    32


        ;Prompt user:
        lea     rdi,    [rel prompt]        ; First argument is address of message
        call    _puts                       ; puts(message)

        push    1000 ; Wait 1 second (Sleep time is in milliseconds)
        call    Sleep

        lea     rdi,    [rel prompt] ; Print hello again
        call    _puts

        xor     rax,    rax                 ; Return 0
        leave
        ret

        section   .data

prompt:
    db      "Hello!", 0
```

Both these files are saved to Desktop/Program. I'm trying to compile it using NASM and GCC, my compiler invocation is:

```
nasm -f macho64 Program.asm && gcc Program.o Sleep.s -o Program && ./Program
```

But I get the error:

```
"Sleep", referenced from:
      _main in Program.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z5Sleepi)
  "std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&)", referenced from:
      void std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&) in Sleep-7749e0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Changing the code to "extern __Z5Sleepi" and calling "__Z5Sleepi" instead of Sleep doesn't seem to fix the problem. (I get the same error message just without the "Maybe you meant __Z5Sleepi" bit. I also tried using _Sleep instead of Sleep without success.) What am I doing wrong? How do I properly use and link this C++ subroutine with my assembly program? Is the method I am using so far to do this just wrong from the ground up?

Any help is much appreciated, browsing stack overflow, there seem to be a lot of questions regarding this but none of them actually go into the linking process. (And they seem to be asking about linking assembly with C++, not C++ with assembly.) I am using NASM and GCC to compile, and my platform is Mac OSX.

Comment: First, use `g++` for linking. To get rid of name mangling, use `extern C` in your c++ source.

Comment: @Jester Scratch that last comment. My asm file was still using __Z5Sleepi instead of Sleep. Now, using _Sleep the program compiles and executes. Except now, when it's supposed to pause for 1 second, I get a segmentation fault. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: As you are probably aware (since you used it for `puts` correctly) you have to put argument in `rdi` not on the stack. Hence `push 1000 ` should be `mov edi, 1000`.

Comment: @Jester It works now! Thank you so much, I never knew that rdi applied to my own C++ functions as well. Thank you for enlightening me to that. Would you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: The arg-passing part is a duplicate of [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989).  There's probably a duplicate of the name-mangling part, too, somewhere.  Yup, `extern "C"` for [How to call C++ functions in my assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3911578)

Comment: Even though you got this working, I strongly recommend that you write your main function in C++ and have it call your assembly function. Also link using g++, as @Jester also recommended. This will ensure that the C++ runtime library is initialized properly.

Comment: @prl I totally agree. The only reason I am doing this in assembly is for learning purposes. I'm trying to teach myself assembly. Maybe one day it'll come in handy. One day...

Comment: @SectorSam Generally, the easiest way to find out how to do things like this is to call the C or C++ compiler with the option `-S` to let it generate assembly code.  Then you can see how the C compiler does it and copy its code.  I learned a lot about assembly this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jester pointed out, the problem arose from two things. One was I needed to change the Sleep.cpp program to use extern "C", like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

extern "C" void Sleep(int TimeMS);
extern "C"
{
   void Sleep(int TimeMs) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(TimeMs));
   }
}
```

This prevents the compiler from "name mangling" the function. Doing that changed the compiled function name of Sleep() from "__Z5Sleepi" to "_Sleep" and alleviated my linker errors.

Then I changed my compiler invocation to link with `g++` instead of `gcc`, to link the C++ standard library for functions like `std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for`, as well as the C standard library.

```
nasm -f macho64 Program.asm && g++ Program.o Sleep.o -o Program && ./Program
```

After this, the compiler told me I needed to change `extern Sleep` to `extern _Sleep` and much the same with `call _Sleep` instead of `call Sleep`, because OS X decorates C symbol names with a leading `_`.

After I did all this, the program linked properly but produced a segmentation fault. Jester pointed out the reason for this is that x86-64 calling conventions don't pass integer/pointer function parameters on the stack.  You use the registers in the same way you would call _printf or _puts, because those library functions also follow the same standard calling convention.

In the x86-64 System V calling convention (used on OS X, Linux, and everything other than Windows), [`rdi` is parameter 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call).

So I changed `push 1000` to `mov rdi, 1000`

After all these changes were made, the program compiles correctly and does exactly what it should: Print Hello!, wait 1 second, then print it again.

Comment: you need use decorated name of the enclosing function. dont know how get it in gcc, in msvc it returned by `__FUNCDNAME__` macro. can be looked in object file for example. in msvc possible print `__FUNCDNAME__ ` macro at compile time - for get exactly name and use it in asm code

Comment: You don't *need* to use the mangled name if `extern "C"` works for you.  But if you need to call a member function, or don't want an extra wrapper around a C++ function that you need to not be `extern "C"`, then yeah you'd want to call the mangled name from asm.  Probably best to just copy/paste it from `nm` output or something, but there might be a way to have gcc make it for you.

Comment: *but there might be a way to have gcc make it for you* - in *msvc* we can put `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__ ))` inside function body and this print exactly function name, wich need use in asm. also possible situation when in *c++* code exist several functions with the same name (different by params). this can not be used with `extern "C"`. `extern "C"` of course most simply solution but not always the best

Comment: The reason I used `extern "C"` is simply because I am writing this program in assembly, and typing in a name like "__Z5Sleepi" is very tedious and error prone. (I know I personally would type it in wrong almost every time.) I'm not saying there aren't other ways of doing these types of things, this is just the way I use.